# MS Graph Access Forbidden

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

This code works using the Microsoft Graph Explorer using the SharePoint Search, but when I export it to a .NET Core App it seems to go wrong due to access issues. Am I missing something here?

```
var requests = new List<SearchRequestObject>()
{
    new SearchRequestObject
    {
        EntityTypes = new List<EntityType>()
        {
            EntityType.Site
        },
        Query = new SearchQuery
        {
            QueryString = "tryingAgain"
        }
    }
};
 
await _graphServiceClient.Search
    .Query(requests)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Stack trace error:

```
Status Code: Forbidden
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Access forbidden, insufficient access permission
Message: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.

Inner error:
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.SearchEntityQueryRequest.PostAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet_graph.Controllers.HomeController.Profile() in C:\Repo\Call-MSGraph\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 111
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Have you provided credentials for the .NET Core App to authenticate with MS Graph API?

Comment: Yes the access token is being passed

Answer (score 1):

What permission did you grant for the app? According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#scope-search-based-on-entity-types), the app need to have at least permission Sites.Read.All to search sites.

[image]